# How to load a multi page template in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery mobile and I am changing to a multi page template that contains multiple pages in it.  An event is triggering this code:

```
$.mobile.changePage("pages.html");
```

The pages.html file has:

```
<div data-role="page" data-title="page1" id="page1">    
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-theme="a">back</a>  
        <h1>page1</h1>        
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">          
        This is page1 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"> 
            <li><a href="#page2">page2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- content -->        
</div><!-- /page --> 


<div data-role="page" data-title="page2" id="page2">    
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-theme="a">back</a>        
        <h1>page2</h1>        
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">          
        This is page 2
    </div><!-- content -->        
</div><!-- /page -->
```

The changePage works, but it only brings in the first page, not the second into the DOM.  Therefore when I click on the page2 link it does not go to page 2 because it is not in the DOM.  How do I use changePage to bring in the entire file (pages.html) so I have access to the other pages in that file?